# React Display Data from API Fetch & Map

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

i'm attempting to learn React by making a movie web app. Im trying to pull upcoming movies from a movie api, and display information from it, however i keep getting an error:

> Line 37:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression  no-unused-expressions

Please excuse me as im not too familiar with this framework and im not a JS pro. Heres my code:

```
    export default class Upcoming extends Component {

    state = {
        upcomingMovies: []
      }

      fetchUpcoming() {
          fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`)
              // We get the API response and receive data in JSON format...
              .then(response => response.json())
              // ...then we update upcomingMovies State
              .then(data =>
                  this.setState({
                      upcomingMovies: data.results
                  })
              )
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchUpcoming();
    }

  render() {

    return(
        <Container>
            { this.state.upcomingMovies.map((upcomingMovie) => {
                console.log(upcomingMovie);
                const title = upcomingMovie.title;
                console.log(title);
                <h1>{title}</h1>
            })}

        </Container>
    )

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Map function should return something to generate ui.

```
    export default class Upcoming extends Component {

    state = {
        upcomingMovies: []
      }

      fetchUpcoming() {
          fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`)
              // We get the API response and receive data in JSON format...
              .then(response => response.json())
              // ...then we update upcomingMovies State
              .then(data =>
                  this.setState({
                      upcomingMovies: data.results
                  })
              )
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchUpcoming();
    }

  render() {

    return(
        <Container>
            { this.state.upcomingMovies.map((upcomingMovie) => (
               <h1>{upcomingMovie.title}</h1>
            ))}
        </Container>
    )

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return statement in the last line of your map function. It should be `return <h1>{title}</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You should write `fetchUpcoming` by using arrow function. So, you can use `this.setState()` method on scope of `fetchUpcoming` function. EX:

```
const fetchUpcoming = async() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
    );
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return this.setState({
                      upcomingMovies: responseJson.data.results
                  })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```